# Prime Modified Z-Factorials

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, factorial

Let me explain one by one the above terms...

We will call \$\text{Z-Factorial}(n)\$ of a positive integer \$n\$, \$n!\$ (i.e. \$n\$ factorial) without any trailing zeros.
So, \$\text{Z-Factorial}(30)\$ is \$26525285981219105863630848\$ because \$30!=265252859812191058636308480000000\$

We will call `Modified Z-Factorial` of \$n\$, the \$\text{Z-Factorial}(n) \mod n\$.
So, `Modified Z-Factorial` of \$30\$, is \$\text{Z-Factorial}(30) \mod 30\$ which is \$26525285981219105863630848 \mod 30 = 18\$

We are interested in those \$n\$'s for which the `Modified Z-Factorial of n` is a Prime Number

***Example***

The number \$545\$ is **PMZ** because \$\text{Z-Factorial}(545) \mod 545 = 109\$ which is prime

Here is a list of the first values of \$n\$ that produce `Prime Modified Z-Factorial (PMZ)`

```
5,15,35,85,545,755,815,1135,1165,1355,1535,1585,1745,1895,1985,2005,2195,2495,2525,2545,2615,2705,2825,2855,3035,3085,3155,3205,3265,3545,3595,3695,3985,4135,4315,4385,4415,4685,4705,4985,5105,5465,5965,6085,6155,6185,6385,6415,6595...
```

**Task**

The above list goes on and your task is to find the \$k\$th ***PMZ***

**Input**

A positive integer \$k\$

**Output**

The \$kth\$ ***PMZ***

**Test Cases**

here are some **1-indexed** test cases.
Please state which indexing system you use in your answer to avoid confusion.
Your solutions need only work within the bounds of your language's native integer size.

```
input -> output     
 1        5     
 10       1355       
 21       2615     
 42       5465     
 55       7265      
 100      15935
 500      84815
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: I think we have `Z-Factorial(755) mod 755 = 151`, which is prime. Yet it's not included in your list. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right! Let me fix this...

Comment: Do you mind me adding in some MathJax to the question body? It's slightly hard to read with all the code blocks

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing be my guest!

Comment: Hope you like it, feel free to revert any changes you don't like!

Comment: Presumably, our solutions need only work within the bounds of our language's native integer size in practice?

Comment: @Shaggy Absolutely yes

Comment: Please could you clarify the 'within the bounds of your language's native integer size' ruling.  If this refers only to the sizes of the input ```k``` and output ```pmz_k```, then for the highest input ```k``` we can only use calculations that never exceed ```k``` itself (which will be difficult, since the first step is likely to be a multiplication).  If it refers to the sizes of the numbers that are handled 'internally' by the program's calculation steps, then the straightforward approach of 'kth_prime_of( remove_zeros( factorial( n ) ) MOD n )' already exceeds a 4-byte integer for k=3...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Of course I am referring to numbers that are handled internally... Sorry if that was not clear

Comment: It was kind-of clear, but I wanted to check before posting an answer that only works up to k=2!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
!Dt0Ḍ%⁸Ẓµ#Ṫ
```

A full program reading from STDIN which prints the result to STDOUT.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//IUR0MOG4jCXigbjhupLCtSPhuar//zY)**

#### How?

```
!Dt0Ḍ%⁸Ẓµ#Ṫ - Main Link: no arguments
         #  - set n=0 (implicit left arg) and increment getting the first
                (implicit input) values of n which are truthy under:
        µ   -   the monadic chain (f(n)):
!           -     factorial -> n!
 D          -     convert from integer to decimal digits
  t0        -     trim zeros
    Ḍ       -     convert from decimal digits to integer
      ⁸     -     chain's left argument, n
     %      -     modulo
       Ẓ    -     is prime?
          Ṫ - tail
            - implicit print
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah, I thought I could remove the `³`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman ...turns out I can if I use a link rather than a chain, so back to 13 again :)

Comment: Nice! When you are done golfing I'm really curious what the 5 is doing. I only know Jelly mildly and it seems quite odd (removing it sometimes causes off by one errors?).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman `5` is the starting value of the incremental search which otherwise defaults to the input (so we find the first `n` integers starting at `5` counting up that satisfy the property rather than the first `n` integers starting at `n`) - the `Ṫ` just gives us the last one. EDIT: Although saying that we can get rid of it by using STDIN...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks for the questions, you helped me golf it by 2!

Comment: Not the most usual method of golf help, but if it works it works :) I was wondering why it wasn't beating my test program in Pyth by more since you had access to trim, now it seems much cleaner!

Comment: can we get an explanation?

Comment: @NooneAtAll sure thing, added it; I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  16 bytes

```
[N!0ÜN%pi®>©¹Q#N
```

**Input** is **1-based** k.

**Outputs** the k-th PMZ.

Explanation:

```
[N!0ÜN%pi®>©¹Q#N
[                     Start infinite loop
 N!                   Factorial of the index
   0Ü                 Remove trailing zeros
     N%               Mod index
       p              Is prime?
        i             If it is:
         ®>©          Increment the value stored in register c (initially -1)
            ¹Q        Is the value equals the input?
              #N      If it does, push the index (which is the PMZ) and break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2k/R4PAcP9WCzEPr7A6tPLQzUNnv/38TAA)

Comment: Seems like you’re not aware of the `µ` built-in. 9 bytes: [`µNN!0ÜN%p`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0FY/P0WDw3P8VAv@/zcBAA)

Comment: How did I missed that?! Thank you.. Should I add it to this answer?

Comment: Yep feel free to edit it in!

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 58 bytes

```
D,f,@,Rb*BDBGbUdb*!!*BFJiA%P
x:?
Wx,`y,+1,`z,$f>y,`x,-z
Oy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQScoScvJxck9KTQlSUtRUcvJzSvTUTWAq8LKniu8QiehUkfbUCehSkclza5SJ6FCR7eKy7/y////RpYA)

Times outs for \$k \ge 30\$ on TIO

### How it works

```
D,f,@,			; Define a function, f, taking 1 argument, n
			; Example:		STACK = [30]
	Rb*		; Factorial		STACK = [265252859812191058636308480000000]
	BD		; Convert to digits	STACK = [2 6 5 ... 0 0 0]
	BGbU		; Group adjacents	STACK = [[2] [6] [5] ... [8] [4] [8] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
	db*!!		; If last is all 0s
	*BF		; 	remove it	STACK = [[2] [6] [5] ... [8] [4] [8]]
	Ji		; Join to make integer	STACK = [26525285981219105863630848]
	A%		; Mod n			STACK = [18]
	P		; Is prime?		STACK = [0]
			; Return top value	0

x:?			; Set x to the input

Wx,			; While x > 0
	`y,+1,		;	y = y + 1
	`z,$f>y,	;	z = f(y)
	`x,-z		;	x = x - z
			; We count up with y
			; If y is PMZ, set z to 1 else 0
			; Subtract z from x, to get x PMZs

Oy			; Output y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

0-indexed. Only works, in practice, for `0` & `1` as once we go over `21!` we exceed JavaScript's `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

```
ÈÊsÔsÔuX j}iU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yMpz1HPUdVggan1pVQ&input=MQ)

```
ÈÊsÔsÔuX j}iU     :Implicit input of integer U
È                 :Function taking an integer X as argument
 Ê                :  Factorial
  s               :  String representation
   Ô              :    Reverse
    sÔ            :  Repeat (There has to be a shorter way to remove the trailing 0s!)
      uX          :  Modulo X
         j        :  Is prime?
          }       :End function
           iU     :Pass all integers through that function, returning the Uth one that returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>99</s> 93 bytes

*Edit: -6 bytes (and -4 bytes from arbitrary-precision version) thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
k=scan();while(k){F=F+1;z=gamma(F+1);while(!z%%5)z=z/10;x=z%%F;k=k-(x==2|all(x%%(2:x^.5)))};F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpLDsIgFAD3nuI1hggxfkrSTQkuOYAHMHlBrARKDaURUc9eu3E3k5k4z06OGgNl4nm33lDH3kqqbS2K7LDvkS78b1UhpGFFlkN9FFkupoSTbkezlPyD3tNMCOVtvuwbxthXqJmvVmsIQzItaPR68pjsEEYwWRtzhfNmBNR6ipgMhKk30S4bRAydgdsQAcMLbHhMCU68Aph/)

Uses the straightforward approach, following the steps of the explanation.  Unfortunately goes out of limits of [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s numerical accuracy at factorial(21), so fails for any k>2.

An arbitrary-precision version (which is not limited to small k, but is less golf-competitive) is:
**[R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gmp, [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEABfs7CLWJtCL8a95hnCVkIMSYqkgjGtb4@UHoeZyS36KUv@oksvaoGXh8xI@vP00WKg1bAs3eRdRXNSpCs7SUkOOKIKMN4UVa5wAdXrsh9@fltn8y4N6cDhjIV52CRGLADDtdy7keinTVN9@wM)**

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYpLDsIgFAD3nuI1hggxfkrSTQkuOYAHMHlBrARKDaURUc9eu3E3k5k4z06OGgNl4nm33lDH3kqqbS2K7LDvkS78b1UhpGFFlkN9FFkupoSTbkezlPyD3tNMCOVtvuwbxthXqJmvVmsIQzItaPR68pjsEEYwWRtzhfNmBNR6ipgMhKk30S4bRAydgdsQAcMLbHhMCU68Aph/). Similar golfs can (probably) be applied to the `gmp` approach

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!foṗS%ȯ↔↔ΠN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzEt/@HO6cGqJ9Y/apsCROcW@P3//98IAA)

### Explanation

```
!foṗS%ȯ↔↔ΠN
 f        N filter list of natural numbers by:
         Π  take factorial
       ↔↔   reverse twice, remove trailing zeros
     S%     mod itself
    ṗ       is prime?
!           get element at index n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>89 ... 79</s>  77 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=y=>y%10n?(p=k=>y%--k?p(k):~-k||--n?g(x*=++i):i)(y%=i):g(y/10n))(x=i=2n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoIwEADvvKIXkq24Cl404MJbCBZSS9qGNoYq@nRrPc0kk7n3j94Ni7QetbmJOFLU1MJEgdqQV6XuwJL6O6LqLChef1BtG6LuJlh3VBSS15JDyCnJBOGYJs5hJUknzeNoFpiFZ5oRq5qEK7FzYlFw9soYG4x2ZhaH2Uyg92yENDfZO36N9TK1iOh8Pyh08inoUpblDw)

Comment: `g=y` (15 chars)

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive What do you mean?

Comment: A bad, dirty joke. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>145</s> <s>140</s> <s>138</s> 129 bytes

```python
def f(n,r=0):
 c=d=2
 while r<n:
  c+=1;d*=c
  while 1>d%10:d//=10
  i=d%c;r+=i==2or i and min(i%j for j in range(2,i))
 return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BCgIxDETv/YpBWNhqxbbqRY0/Ih6WtutGNEpdEb9@bfGUmZdkSJ7fcXjIeppi6tG3YjJZvVMIFMkrfAa@JeSDFISwILePcwpF/xvuGBtnd3G1ImcLZYpN2OcFMZF/ZDA6ibiztNxc0RdyBQtyJ5fUesNaK@Q0vrMgTPK@v0A4OQNnDXypG2@w3VZvz0rV/dSFoUbU4XoT8MwsY1u5wWx5nJnyRnVaTz8)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>126</s> 125 bytes

```python
def f(n,r=0):
 c=d=2
 while r<n:
	c+=1;d*=c
	while d%10<1:d/=10
	i=d%c
	r+=i==2or i and min(i%j for j in range(2,i))
 print c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5NCsIwEIXXnVM8hEKrEZOgm@p4EXFRktZO0VGiIp6@Nrga3vd@mMf3NdzVT1PsevSVmsS2bgiBI3vCZ5Brh3TQhoqwYrePSw5U/HEsnT24Jm7YWSqEYzlbacXC7O8JglYjbqKVlCP6mYwQRWr10lXeSF0THkn0hTDp@/YE4@QMnDXw8916g90ua3smyvWuDUNeyOH5n383Q4PF@rgwVPRVlvX0Aw)

---

Explanation: Keep dividing by 10 as long as the current factorial is divisible by 10, and then check the factorial modulo current number for primality.

Thanks to *caird coinheringaahing* for -20 bytes and *Dominic van Essen* for -9 bytes!

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY/RasMwDEWf46@4BAJJ6zHbtC9p1R8pewi2s6i0SnETxr4@tTe9iHskDtLzd5lmcdsW4oixFZ3IdL2Cp0BO4Wfie0Q6S68qvyd7CjvyqvrHMi8IjTV9oPBpjaqYQpOnPIKJ3JzAFzdIwIOl5eaGMaMbWJAG@Y6t09x1fcpahRSXNQn8JuvjBcLValij4XI/OI3jsWTzpVSRxMFPxVOW87G5noll@eMa9cel1vmZkrrtDQ) by switching to Python 2, or [140](https://tio.run/##JU/LasMwELzrK4aAwWpVIqnJxe36R0IORpLjDck6qDYlX@9I5LTzYph9PJdplu9ti2nE2IrJZHWnECiSV/if@JaQf6VICJ/kfuIHhYLfhswLYuNsFynu984Wgyk2NcBjgeTnDO79IBF3lpabK8YiXcGCPMgltd6w1l0u1Qo5LWsWhE3W@x8IJ2fgrIEv9@ANjsfK7VmpWpKGMNWeGq7zgEdmWdqqG@y@@p0pH1Wm9fYC) sticking with Python 3

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY5NCsIwEIXXnVM8hEKrEZOgm@p4EXFRktZO0VGiIp6@Nrga3vd@mMf3NdzVT1PsevSVmsS2bgiBI3vCZ5Brh3TQhoqwYrePSw5U/HEsnT24Jm7YWSqEYzlbacXC7O8JglYjbqKVlCP6mYwQRWr10lXeSF0THkn0hTDp@/YE4@QMnDXw8916g90ua3smyvWuDUNeyOH5n383Q4PF@rgwVPRVlvX0Aw) using Python 2

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY/BCgIxDETv/YpBWNhqxbbqRY0/Ih6WtutGNEpdEb9@bfGUmZdkSJ7fcXjIeppi6tG3YjJZvVMIFMkrfAa@JeSDFISwILePcwpF/xvuGBtnd3G1ImcLZYpN2OcFMZF/ZDA6ibiztNxc0RdyBQtyJ5fUesNaK@Q0vrMgTPK@v0A4OQNnDXypG2@w3VZvz0rV/dSFoUbU4XoT8MwsY1u5wWx5nJnyRnVaTz8) in Python 3 using ```;``` and some of the Python 2 tricks...

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>129</s> 111 bytes

```hs
g n
 |n`mod`10>0=n
 |0<1=g$div n 10
f=(!!)[n|n<-[1..],let p=mod(g$product[1..n])n,[x|x<-[2..p],mod p x<1]==[p]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NboMwEIX3nGKCWNjKlNoEp6mEc4J21aVlNSgQiALGSpzWSNydmlaVsns/32heW94uddfNcwMmgskc@qE6cLZncrGs4LJJqvMXGOAsOkmyWlFlJlM8KZ6mGrvagZXhhjSJvQ7V/eiWwmhqUPnJBy5LU6sxIGDBF1xLqazWcwseRgkxiWG9BnJrh2/wdNExBbmHhziB038Fz4/F@BeS2tv66OqKxlHUl2cDEvrSvn@CvbsPd30zoH7fTcTjSMMmwlFQJJwh34hFZRyzLRc0DCOCMdzlu@ACEAjxugkyz1Dk24UVAl@yoH4A)

`g` removes `0`s from number.

`f` takes `k`th element from an infinite list comprehension where:
`[x|x<-[2..p],mod p x==0]==[p]` is `prime` condition( compares list of divisors of `p` and a list of just p).

And `p` is `mod(g$foldr(*)1[1..n])n` the modulo of factorial passed through `g`.

Saved 18 thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)

Comment: Wow, this is way more concise than the one I got. I think you can reduce it even more to [123 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7faoMwGMXvfYqDeJHQzCXWtB2YPsF2tUuRVarVUo2hplsE372LHYPenT@/j@@05Xipu@5@b6ADYNaHfqgOgu@5enieCdVE1fkbGoIHJzjVlaONbHmp4aJczzp7yUUcF6yrLYzy56SJzHWobke7FLqgmuVudp5L4tgUzCMwcJkolMpNUdxbOEwKIQmxWoGM7fADRxcdUqg9nuIIp/8Kr8/F9BeS2pn6aOuKhkHQl2cNhb40H18wN/tpr@8a@ePdTBybqN9EBJOUEcGZWMtFJYIlGyGpH0Yk52yX7rzzgCfk29rLNGEy3SyslGybePUL)

Comment: Make that [113](https://tio.run/##TY5NboMwFIT3nGKCWNiKS22C01TCOUG76hJZDQoEooKxEtIaibtTk6pSdvPzPb1piutX1bbzXMMEwGQOXV8eBN9zdfc8E6qOyvM3DAQPToqsVjQ3k8mechHHmrXVAKv8Eakje@nL23FYCqOpYbmbnOeSOLaaeQQWLhNaqdxqPTdwGBVCEmK9Brk2/Q8cXXRIofZ4iCOc/is8PxbjX0gqZ6vjUJU0DIKuOBsodIV9/4S9DR/D5c0gv7@biGMj9ZuIYJIyIjgTG7moRLBkKyT1w4jknO3SnXce8IR83XiZJkym24WVkr0kXv0C)

Comment: Thanks @user I don't know these tricks!